# Combining files even if one is missing?

Tags: python, pandas

I read daily files based on the filename, which includes a date, and append them. Sometimes a file is missing though for a random date. This stops my code from running - I put a Try Except and it allows the code to continue to run but any dataframe with a missing date within my range will be None.

Is there a method to read all of the existing files and combine them even if a date is missing? This has been a headache for a long time now.

```
start_date = (central_time - pd.Timedelta(days = 4)) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin()
end_date = central_time - pd.Timedelta(days = 3)
days = ((pd.Timestamp(end_date) - pd.Timestamp(start_date)) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int)


def last_n_days(filename, num_of_days, include_curr = True):
    f = '%m_%d_%Y'
    curr = end_date
    if include_curr:
        yield curr.strftime(f)
    for num in range(num_of_days):
        curr = curr - dt.timedelta(days = 1)
        yield curr.strftime(f)


def read_concat_file(filename, parse_dates = True):
    df_list = []
    try:
        for file_date in last_n_days(filename, days, False):
            read_file = '{}{}{}{}'.format(ftp_location, ftp_filename, file_date, '.csv')
            print('Appending file {}'.format(read_file))
            df = pd.read_csv(read_file, parse_dates = parse_dates)
            df_list.append(df)
        return pd.concat(df_list)
    except IOError:
        print('File does not exist:', read_file)
```

I like the behavior of glob.glob where it ignores if a file is missing, but I prefer to be able to read a certain number of days or read based on the start of the month (to create a month-to-date file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I put a Try Except and it allows the code to continue to run but any dataframe with a missing date within my range will be None.

I don't know if this is true. If a file is not found, your `for-loop`  prematurely exits and never restarts. You would need to put the `try/except` block inside the `for` loop instead:

```
def read_concat_file(filename, parse_dates = True):
    df_list = []
    try:
        for file_date in last_n_days(filename, days, False):
            try:
                read_file = '{}{}{}{}'.format(ftp_location, ftp_filename, file_date, '.csv')
                print('Appending file {}'.format(read_file))
                df = pd.read_csv(read_file, parse_dates = parse_dates)
                df_list.append(df)
            except IOError:
                print('File does not exist:', read_file)  
        return pd.concat(df_list)
```

> Is there a method to read all of the existing files and combine them even if a date is missing?

You can provide your own date parser, and tell it to create a default date when the `date` is empty:

```
import datetime as dt

def date_parser(date):
    if date is None or date == "":
        return dt.datetime()
    else:
        return dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%d%b%Y')
...
pd.read_csv(read_file, parse_dates=parse_dates, date_parser=date_parser)
```

Comment: Say I am reading 3 different files (file_a, file_b, file_c) for all dates in December 2015. My current code will read all of the files no problem, but if one date in file_c is missing, then that entire dataframe is None so I can't perform operations on it. Hope that is more clear.

Comment: I see so the missing date is inside the file - updated answer. You need to pass your own date parser, so make sure you tweak `strptime` to accept the format you expect. If the date is missing, then you return a `datetime` object with today's date instead.

Comment: Adding the try except into the loop, as you suggested, worked perfectly. Thanks.